# Como selecionar as últimas 3 colunas em um data frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho uma base de dados que é atualizada mensalmente, que possui 7 colunas: `USUÁRIO`, e os últimos 6 meses do ano com a quantidade de compras de cada mês.

Segue exemplo:

```
print(DADOS)

    USUÁRIO  JAN  FEV  MAR  ABR  MAI  JUN 
     001      4    3    2    0    4    7
     002      1    9    0    1    1    9
     003      0    1    2    3    4    0
     004      2    4    0    8    0    6
```

A dificuldade se encontra quando necessito por exemplo selecionar os últimos 3 meses para calcular uma soma.
Selecionando pelo o nome da coluna aparentemente resolve o problema...

```
DADOS = DADOS %>%
select(ABR,MAI,JUN) %>%
mutate(SOMA = sum(ABR,MAI,JUN))

print(DADOS)

USUÁRIO  JAN  FEV  MAR  ABR  MAI  JUN  SOMA 
 001      4    3    2    0    4    7    20
 002      1    9    0    1    1    9    21
 003      0    1    2    3    4    0    10
 004      2    4    0    8    0    6    20
```

Mas o problema começa na próxima atualização mensal, que ao invés de buscar os últimos 3 meses (`MAI,JUN,JUL`), ele continua buscando (`ABR,MAI,JUN`), parece óbvio que isso daria errado, mas a questão é como selecionar as últimas 3 colunas de um data frame que não busque pelo nome e sim pela posição?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `tail` do `R` padrão seleciona as n últimas observações de um vetor. Por exemplo,

```
tail(letters, 10)
## [1] "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

seleciona as 10 últimas letras do alfabeto. Se tu combinar a função `tail` com `names` aplicado no data frame, é possível selecionar as três últimas colunas do data frame, não importando quais sejam elas. Veja no exemplo abaixo como fazer isto:

```
head(iris)
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
iris %>% 
  select(tail(names(.), 3)) %>%
  head()
##   Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Marcus Nunes, vou testar.

Comment: @IzakMandrak se a resposta do Marcus Nunes lhe satisfez favor considere marcá-la como a solução do seu problema.

Comment: @FlavioSilva assim que eu testar a solução e descobrir se ela satisfaz ou não, irei aceitar a resposta sem problemas, assim como fiz com as minhas outras perguntas. Obrigado por lembrar.

Comment: @Marcus Nunes é possível usar operações matemáticas depois do uso do `tail`? É possível selecionar as últimas 3 colunas e depois somá-las?